# WebGL model viewer using Three.js as a DOM element in HTML

Tags: three.js, webgl

I want to have a 3D model viewer on my website that runs from Three.js as a DOM element in HTML. Is this possible? Any examples?

Comment: Note: I looked into your profile from your previous question, and saw this question. The reason it got downvoted is that recommendations on which software/tool to use is not allowed b/c of the subjective information that usually results from these discussions. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for more information on what type of questions you should be asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at [GLAM](http://tparisi.github.io/glam/) project by Tony Parisi?
He's giving you a declarative way to build up 3D scenes.